# Google Map API geocode error with country alpha2 code for IN (India) and CA (Canada)

Tags: api, dictionary

I have an app using google map API to show the country on map by their alpha2 code, but I run into problems for In (India) and CA (Canada). The code is following:

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

the address variable in the above function can take the country's full name (India, Canada), but my application feeds the alpha2 code. My temporary solution is hard code 'IN' and 'CA' in the above function, but I am wondering if there's a better strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the Google Map API, I came to understand that the API has a region bias. By default, it has a bias for where the request is sent from. For example, if you are from the U.S. and query for 'IN', as the region bias is the U.S., Google Map will first try to locate 'IN', which happens to be Indiana.

I also came to know that there're two ways to override the region bias by:

1. setting the 'region' parameter in: `{'address' : address, 'region': 'cn'};` **// set the region bias to China**
2. using the `componentRestrictions` option.